# Why <ul> tag is used in HTML?

Tags: html, html-lists

So im just getting started learning html/css and just don´t really understand the use of the `<ul>` tag in html.

I mean i get this explanation:

"The HTML  tag is used for specifying an unordered list, which groups a collection of items having no numerical order. When changing the order of list items, the meaning does not change. Usually, the items of an unordered list are displayed with a bullet."

but when i create a list for example:

`<li>` apples `</li>`
`<li>` pears `</li>`
`<li>` bananas `</li>`

i get the same result as i would get with the  tag around:

`<ul>`
`<li>` apples `</li>`
`<li>` pears `</li>`
`<li>` bananas `</li>`

`</ul>`

so im guessing the `<ul>` tag is mainly for tecnical stuff, like search engines and less for the apearence of the website?

Comment: This link about semantics on MDN should help: [Semantics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics)

Comment: that really helped. thank you!

Comment: the `ul` tag is technically required to keep your markup valid. Without the `ul`, `ol` or `dl` then the `li` elements would not be corrected nested in the DOM. Web browsers have changed greatly over the years - there are still browsers around I am sure that would baulk at badly formed HTML that you might get.

Comment: `li` is just a list item. Without CSS the browser doesn't know if the list is ordered (`ol`) or unordered (`li`) and just guesses. It'll be displayed correctly because of that correction mechanism but you shouldn't rely on that because your source HTML is invalid.